# Why does my STM32F407 discovery flashed software take effect after replugging the cable?

Tags: embedded, stm32, keil

I'm using Keil to flash the software to on stm32f407 discovery.
But the software only starts working when I pullout the JLINK cable and plug it again.
Why is that?

Comment: Latest version of Keil have some issue with "Reset and Run". Try to start debug and run the code(F5) then exit debug.

Answer (score 3):

By default uVision holds the target in RESET after flashing with the the Download (F8) function.  I would argue that this is a safety feature - if your code controls some electro-mechanical system for example you might not want it to start-up spontaneously.

You can change this behaviour via Flash->Configure Flash Tools->Settings...

[image]

Alternatively if you load by running the debugger, it will start-up and by default breakpoint at `main()` - that default can be changed to run straight through.  Any explicitly set breakpoints will cause a halt of course.